# Coursera's course "How to Win a Data Science Competition"

Tags: competitions, coursera

The Coursera Course "How to Win a Data Science Competition".

Has onyone seen it? How is the quality of it? Would you recommend it?

Answer (score 3):

It's a technically rigorous course.

Recommend? It depends on what your goal is.

- Definitely, if your goal is to compete on Kaggle.
- Not really, if you want to improve practical ML.

Remember, Kaggle is kind of Formula 1. The fastest car wins. But in the real world, you don't always need a Formula 1 car. Sometimes you need an SUV, sometimes you need a van, sometimes a Tesla ....